# Can you help me to join 3 tables and make foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables

1. `Table 1` : ID_Customer char(10), Name varchar(50)
2. `Table 2` : ID_Bill Char(10), Status varchar(50), **ID_Customer char(10).FK, ID_Offer char(10) FK**
3. `Table 3` : ID_Offer char(10), Package varchar(50), **ID_Customer char(10).FK**

I want that 3 relationship and have foreign key and if I join 3 tables can see that data like this

```
ID_Customer|Name|ID_Bill|Status|ID_Offer|Package  | 
-----------+----+-------+------+--------+---------+
C001       |Ang |BI001  |Paid  |OF001   |Package A|
```

and that data can see table and the data in the content.

Comment: I don't see any foreign keys.

Comment: You haven't told us how to join, or connect, these tables together.

Comment: Looks like all table's are independent

Comment: Sorry guys i forget to give that Foreign key, i edited now please read again

Comment: that table can be join ike that table 1 relationship to table 2, and table 1 relationship to table 3

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.ID_Customer,
       t1.Name,
       t2.ID_Bill,
       t2.Status,
       t3.ID_Offer,
       t3.Package
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
               ON t1.ID_Customer = t2.ID_Customer
       INNER JOIN table3 t3
               ON t2.ID_Offer = t3.ID_Offer
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very straightforward, SQL basics 101 join.....

```
SELECT
    c.ID_Customer, c.Name, b.ID_Bill, b.Status, o.ID_Offer, o.Package
FROM
    dbo.Customer c  -- "table 1"
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Bill b ON b.ID_Customer = c.ID_Customer   -- "table 2"
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Order o ON o.ID_Customer = c.ID_Customer  -- "table 3"
```